# Android custom view context is null.. how can that be?

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, android-context

I am working on a very simple custom view, my view simply extends view, and has a draw method

```
public class MyView extends View ;



public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    System.out.println("CONTEXT!!! "+context);
}

@Override
public void draw (Canvas canvas){
...
}
```

The XML definition is:

```
<com.mycode.MyView
     android:id="@+id/overlay"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

Android properly tries to instantiate the class, and calls as expected the draw... unfortunately the in the draw method, the context is null.  So I placed in the system.out.println in the constructor to see that the context is not null when instantiated... but that line never gets hit... So what is going on? Am I in some lifecycle that I am not understanding that Android could be calling draw before its finished creating the context?  How the heck do I get Context to be anything but null in this case?

I don't understand how the view could be getting instantiated/inflated to the point of the draw method being called, but have no context.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is hard to say what's going on. Is the layout somehow *inflated* in an Activity or Fragment? Can you post the draw's content?

Comment: Can you try to add the default constructor `public MyView(Context context)` add then a breakpoint to your 2 constructors.

Comment: There is a fragment defined in the XML, but the MyView is not part of any fragment, it is defined directly in the activity_xml

As to the draw, the contents really don't matter, the first line of draw is context.getResources() which fails because context is NULL.

Comment: @VincentD  Adding the MyView(Context context) results in no change, it does not get called and context is still null.

Comment: @user282172 have you seen my answer?

Comment: @Emmanuel it looks like he hasn't seen. I think you are correct but let's wait for op reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View` has 4 constructors (as of API 21). The framework is probably calling   `View(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int)` version of the constructor preventing you from seeing the Log statement.

I do not know how you are getting reference of the `Context`, but my bet is that you are setting something like `this.context = context` inside the constructor that is not being called. Use `View.getContext()` inside `onDraw()` instead.

Comment: My class is simply extending view, so regardless of which constructor the inflating/instantiating calls I would expect it to be available in my subclass, would it not?

For the record I overloaded all 3 constructors at this point and none seem to be getting called the 4th context, attribs, int, int is undefined in my runtime when I attempt to call it on super, so assume that one is part of a higher version than I am targeting... None of them appear to be called.. its as if DRAW is getting called before its constructed... or there is a ctor that I am missing... I am perplexed for sure.

Comment: Okay, my mistake context is defined in the constructor it is getting called... I just missed it in the logs... Stupid human error.... Thanks so much for the help... had a local copy of context that was not getting set and as such, later references were null even though constructor properly had it.  Doh!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark this question as answered.